# Simultaneous diagonalization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector, diagonal

Crossposted and answered [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/364148/152665). The generalised diagonalisation of two matrices `A` and `B` can be done in Matlab via

```
[V,D] = eig(A,B);
```

where the columns of `V` are a the generalised eigenvectors for `A` and `B`, while `D` is a diagonal matrix containing the corresponding generalised eigenvalues (`A`,`B`).

Assuming that `V` are also standard eigenvectors for both `A` and `B`, my goal is to compute the respective eigenvalues (i.e. in the same order of the eigenvectors in `V`) of `A` and `B`. I could do this via

```
eigA = V\A*V;
eigB = V\B*V;
```

However, is there a simpler way to achieve this, i.e. without having to compute the inverse of `V` as in the snippet above?

Comment: @ Massimo Frittelli looks like you've already found an answer on the other website. However you can easily avoid one of the two system inversion by using the property `eigA=eigB*D`. Good luck!

Comment: @bousof Thank you, that actually simplifies my approach.